# C#-program terminates when trying to allocate more than 2GB with cudaMalloc within a C++DLL-method

Tags: c#, c++, windows, cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a C#-program calling a DLL-method written in C++ to get a pointer to memory allocated on my graphics card using cudaMalloc. Later I pass this pointer to some CUDA-Method of the same DLL. This works fine for data up to 2GB. But as soon as I try to keep pointers to more than two 1-GB-data-chunks, the program terminates without any error message:

```
char*_test1 = CudaDllWrapper.getDeviceCharPointerTo1GBData(filename);
char* test2 = CudaDllWrapper. getDeviceCharPointerTo1GBData (filename);
char* test3 = CudaDllWrapper.. getDeviceCharPointerTo1GBData (filename); //program terminates in this line
```

The Cuda-DLL-Code is this:

```
char* getDeviceCharPointerTo1GBData (const char*  a_pcFileName) {
char* pcLargeData  = ReadPreRasteredImageAsChar(a_pcFileName);
char* pcPrerasteredImage_dyn = NULL;
unsigned long long iSourceImageSize_byte = getFileSize(a_pcFileName);
size_t freeMem, total;
cudaMemGetInfo(&freeMem, &total);
if (freeMem > iSourceImageSize_byte)
cudasafe(cudaMalloc((void **)&pcPrerasteredImage_dyn, iSourceImageSize_byte), "Original image allocation ", __FILE__, __LINE__);
else
return NULL;
}
```

As You see, I check for sufficient memory being left on graphics card, but there still seems to be enough memory left and so the DLL-method seems to call `cudaMalloc`, which seems to cause the program being terminated. When I leave the `cudaMalloc` uncalled by passing a bool on the third call of `getDeviceCharPointerTo1GBData`, the program does not terminate anymore.

I am running Windows 7 and now, I am wondering, if WDDM is making my life difficult with its 2GB-limit. But I expected cudaMalloc will simply fail but not that the whole calling C#-application is terminated. Can it be that Windows 7 terminates my program, when it tries to allocate graphics-card-memory past this 2 GB limit? And how can I prevent such a crash returning a nullpointer instead?

Comment: Does the system have enough GPU memory?

Answer (score 1):

The termination was caused to a __debugbreak(); being hit in case of too little memory, which caused an unhandeled exception and thus program termination.